# Cannot connect via Samba on MAC

Tags: networking, mac, samba

My ISP provided me with new Wifi+Modem combo which comes with a spare USB port where I connected my hard drive. The modem supports connection via samba and after creating user credentials, I can connect successfully from Windows, iOS, Android, but just not MAC. There is no error message when connecting via CMD+K, only when entering the credentials I just get stuck.

Now, I do have another router where I can easily connect via SMB and it all works, so the problem seems related to the ISP modem, however, the tech support tells me that the issue is related to the general MAC/Samba protocol mess that I read about online, and that the hybrid box demands a higher SMB standard than apple, hence refuses to allow the connection.

I tried to connect via cifs:// with no success and even looked for alternative OSX samba client which unfortunately are outdated and cannot be run on Catalina.

Is there anything else I can do? Perhaps change settings in the MAC's samba configuration file or something like this?

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: macOS uses SMBv2 by default [as do almost all devices these days], It also supports SMBv3. SMBv1, AFS & CIFS are all deprecated. If another router works as expected, blame the router not the Mac.

Comment: Is there any way to force MAC to use SMBv1? I saw a samba config file in the preferences folder.

Comment: oops, my bad, macOS uses SMBv3 by default, though you can force it back to SMBv2. Nothing should be using SMBv1 these days, not since maybe 2010 has it been the go-to protocol. It & its 'buddy' CIFS, is 2002 technology, old, slow & insecure. You force SMBv1 by using cifs:// If you use smb:// you get v3 by default. Often half the problem is devices using proprietary MS structures like NTLM. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that. I tried connecting via cifs:// without success, I’ll have to see how to force MAC back to SMBv2 and give it a shot.